# excel: color cells of a column if a matching value is found in other column

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I have two columns, column A and column B. I want to highlight/color those cells in column A who have a match in column B.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:

Conditional formatting with this formatting rule:

=NOT(ISERROR(MATCH($A1,$B$1:$B$8,0)))

EDIT: BrakNicku is correct, following is enough:

=MATCH($A1,$B$1:$B$8,0)

Comment: `NOT` and `ISERROR` are redundant. Using `MATCH` is enough.

Comment: match doesn't give true or false values but row number and !NA error

Comment: Row number (integer > 0) is internally converted to TRUE, and you don't have to worry about converting errors to FALSE - using only MATCH you will get exactly the same results for conditional formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Add a third column that's doing a vlookup for A values in B.
Then you can have a conditional format depending on the values of C.